# How do I stop the super key from invoking the Unity Launcher?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, launcher

And yes, I know the Unity launcher is the app-launcher panel on the left of the screen.

How do I make it so that when I hold the `Super` key down the Unity Launcher (Which I have set to hide itself) does NOT appear? 

I have Gnome-Pie installed and set to invoke upon pressing `Super+Button2` and I find the launcher popping up when I do this very annoying.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and therefore have no access to Unity Tweak Tool.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/485303/how-do-i-stop-ubuntu-from-intercepting-the-super-key-when-running-vmware

Answer (score 1):

I looked in `System Settings`>`Keyboard`>`Shortcuts`, but the Unity desktop effect shortcuts are not listed there and cannot be disabled so easily.

I opened `unity-tweak-tool`. Under the "Unity" heading, selected "Additional". Clicked on "Show the launcher." I thought pressing `Backspace` would disable it, but it doesn't work. You can set it to another keybinding, though.

I spend some time digging through `dconf-editor` without any luck finding a way to disable it completely. So, you're probably going to have to set it to something else.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in 12.04?