# How do I prevent the "Super" button from opening the dash?

Tags: shortcut-keys, unity-dash

Is there a way to disable opening the dash when I press the "Super"/"Windows" button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use **CompizConfig Settings Manager**.

It does not come preinstalled with Ubuntu by default, so you probably have to install it first:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Alternatively you can also click this link to install it through your Software Center: <kbd>**[Install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)**</kbd>

When it's installed, launch it with the command `ccsm` or search it in the Dash.
You will see a window like this:

[image: CompizConfig Settings Manager - Plugin Overview]

Select the **<kbd>Ubuntu Unity Plugin</kbd>**, then switch to the **<kbd>Launcher</kbd>** tab in there.

The first option is what you're looking for:

> Key to show the Dash, Launcher and Help Overlay

You can set a new shortcut or entirely disable it using the three buttons on the right.

[image: CompizConfig Settings Manager - Ubuntu Unity Plugin - Launcher]

Comment: Is there a way to disable the dash but keep the <Super>+<number> to launch/switch between applications? I wanted to disable the first so that it wouldn't interfere with the second, but it seems to be all or nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want to stop Ubuntu/Unity from intercepting the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (which is the key with the Windows logo on it).
One possible solution would be to install the unity-tweak-tool as suggested in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485303/how-do-i-stop-ubuntu-from-intercepting-the-super-key-when-running-vmware):

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Launch the unity-tweak-tool. In the 'Unity' section, select 'Additional'. Click on 'Super' next to 'Show the launcher'. Now you can select a different key or key-combination.

Comment: ubuntu 18.04 you also need to do: sudo apt install notify-osd