# change switch windows shortcut failed. <Super>+ Tab

Tags: shortcut-keys

Ubuntu 16.04, I am trying to set switch window shortcut to super + tab.

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows "['<Super>Tab']"`

However, the super(win key) + tab still not work.

I also try unity tweak tools, fail as well.

Any methods to replace alt + tab with super + tab?

Comment: No, there isn't because it's already being used.

Comment: @MichaelBay why is it impossible to cancel the alt+tab shortcut, and create new one?

Comment: In Unity, Super+Tab is already in use.

Answer (score 1):

For alternative, you can try using **Ring Switcher** which is CompizConfig plugin, the plugin offer switching windows with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> key as default shortcut.

Make sure you have install CompizConfig first, to install, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Open CompizConfig, then select Window Management section on left pane. Search for **Ring Switcher** and enable it by ticking the checkbox.

**NOTE:** You might want to disable Super key (the Windows icon) on your keyboard, as the key will trigger unity dash to pop up.

[How do I prevent the "Super" button from opening the dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743440/how-do-i-prevent-the-super-button-from-opening-the-dash)

Answer (score 0):

@Liso the tool you recommend works: CompizConfig.

1. Install CompizConig
2. On the left panel "Desktop", click "Ubuntu Unity Plugin"
3. In "Switcher" tab
4. Set:

   "key to start switcher": `<Super>Tab`

   "key to flip through windows in the Switcher": `<Super>grave`